# Clojure primitive array type metadata

Tags: java, arrays, clojure

I've made a simple performance test: create 900000 size array and read all of it's elements.

```
(time (let [array (byte-array 900000)] 
                (loop [i (- 900000 1)] 
                  (when (< 0 i) 
                    (aget array i) 
                    (recur (- i 1))))))
"Elapsed time: 10.244612 msecs"
```

Then I wanted to determine type of array to create dynamically and here is defined tautology hashmap for simplicity:

```
(def types {:byte-array byte-array :int-array int-array})
```

Now I am running test again and getting a great performance gap:

```
(time (let [array ((types :byte-array) 900000)] 
                (loop [i (- 900000 1)] 
                  (when (< 0 i) 
                    (aget array i) 
                    (recur (- i 1))))))
"Elapsed time: 7190.233155 msecs"
```

And the workaround:

```
(time (let [^bytes array ((types :byte-array) 900000)] 
                (loop [i (- 900000 1)] 
                  (when (< 0 i) 
                    (aget array i) 
                    (recur (- i 1))))))
"Elapsed time: 12.48304 msecs"
```

The problem is how to type hint clojure dynamically? Does anyone know what happens under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure is a compiled language. Your test code will always be first compiled, then executed. Therefore it is obvious that the code cannot be specialized for two different types at the same time.

If you want to support specialization for primitive arrays of different types, your only chance is to employ macros and use compile-time constants to decide which specialization is needed for each macro invocation. You can build convenience around that, for example dispatching to the appropriately compiled function based on detected runtime type of the array.